# SQL Is there any way to improve performance of "like" query on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table contact table like following:

```
-- sql
create table contact (
    id serial,
    phone text,
    email text,
    skype text,
    wechat text,
    primary key (id)
)
```

We need to support fuzzy search across all columns (phone, email, skype, wechat), like

```
select * 
    from contact 
    where phone like '%keyword%' or 
          email like '%keyword%' or 
          skype like '%keyword%' or 
          wechat like '%keyword%' 
    limit 5
```

Is there any way to improve performance of this query?

Gin index and full text search index work with *word* and won't work here, right?

Comment: You could look into [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html) with Postgres.  Other than this, I don't think an index on any column would really help, because your keyword may occur anywhere in the column.

Comment: Mmm, best I can think of is adding a column that is delimiter combined version of the other fields. You can then do that column like %keyword% instead of having to look on all columns.

Comment: You could use a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html). you should create one index based on the concatenation of all these fields (and query accordingly).

Comment: I think you now that the best way would be to redesign "contact" table to use multiple rows per person - ID, contact_string, contact_type ("phone", "skype",...) this way you would have very simple search. As @LaurenzAlbe mentioned - check "pg_trgm" extension for "trigram index".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks very much. trigram index works well even with OR.